# NA for 1 particular date when converting dates from "character" format to "POSIXct" with as.POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

I'm converting a string vector to date format with as.POSIXct().
Here is the strange thing:

```
as.POSIXct("2017-03-26 03:00:00.000",format="%Y-%m-%d %H")

#Gives

"2017-03-26 03:00:00 CEST"

#While

as.POSIXct("2017-03-26 02:00:00.000",format="%Y-%m-%d %H")

#Outputs
NA
```

This is really confusing and frustrating. It seem like the function really doesn't like the specific time:
02:00:00.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `%T` for time.  In the format,  there are minutes, seconds and millseconds.  So, the `%H` is only matching the hour part

```
as.POSIXct("2017-03-26 02:00:00.000",format="%Y-%m-%d %T")
[1] "2017-03-26 02:00:00 EDT"
```

Or to take care of the milliseconds as well

```
as.POSIXct("2017-03-26 02:00:00.000",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
#[1] "2017-03-26 02:00:00 EDT"
```

---

Or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms("2017-03-26 02:00:00.000")
```

Comment: Both your code snippets still outputs NA for me. Could this have to do with that you have "EDT" in your output where I have "CEST"?

Comment: @Niltzable Can you specify the `tz = "CEST"`

Comment: @Niltzable try with lubridate `library(lubridate);ymd_hms("2017-03-26 02:00:00.000")`

Comment: With lubridate it works and outputs: "2017-03-26 02:00:00 UTC". It is probably some issue with "CEST" then. Thank's alot man!

Comment: @Niltzable with that time zone, i get a warning, but if i do `as.POSIXct("2017-03-26 02:00:00.000",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%OS", tz = "Europe/Berlin")#
[1] NA`. may be it is a locale issue for that time especially when there is day light saving and all

Comment: Yes this was a daylight savings issue: "2017-03-26 02:00:00.000" was when we changed to "summer time" 2017 in Sweden.

Comment: @Niltzable so, it would be a time that doesn't exist officially

Answer (score 1):

This was a daylight savings issue, the time:

`"2017-03-26 02:00:00.000"` does not exist in Sweden as we lost an hour this date when changing to "summer time".